# React element's method shows weird behaviour when bound inside map() function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, this

I am in the early days of learning ReactJS and came across very puzzling (and annoying!) issue when rendering multiple elements with Array.prototype.map() method. I've searched for the solution around the web and had a look at couple of books with no success. Here's the code that I am trying to implement:

```
var ExampleComponent = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Click is working");
  },

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      exampleArray: ["one", "two", "three"]
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.exampleArray.map(function(item, index) {
          return (
            <button className={item} key={index} onClick={this.handleClick}>{item}</button>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );   
  }
});
```

Buttons render just fine. I would expect that upon clicking either of them the specified string would be logged in the console. Instead, button click results in page reload... It feels like there is something obvious I am missing here about how React works.

Has anybody come across this issue before? What's the culprit here? Is there a better way to implement the same pattern?

Any input on the problem would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `map()` with the parent context:

```js
// Call map with context.
{this.state.exampleArray.map(function(item, index) {
  return (
    <button className={item} key={index} onClick={this.handleClick}>
      {item}
    </button>
  );
}, this)}

// Call map with implicit context via arrow function.
{this.state.exampleArray.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <button className={item} key={index} onClick={this.handleClick}>
      {item}
    </button>
  );
})}
```

See also [Communicate Between Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input. I've tried your suggestions and unfortunately button clicks still result in page reload. Also when attempting to bind handler explicitly (2nd example) React logs the following: `You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call.`

Comment: @augustinas Thanks for the feedback, I corrected the errors about explicitly binding the event handler in this scenario. I'm not sure what's happening -- something else must be going on here, because `<buttton>` doesn't have a default action anyway. Do you have other code running that could be attaching event handlers to `<button>` clicks? I'd suggest creating a reproducible example in something like jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks again @JMM! Your answer was absolutely correct, it works like a charm now. I've commented out `event.preventDefault()` at some point of the debug process and that's why I had problems checking your solution...

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I guess without `@type`, `<button>` defaults to being a submit button if in a form (I'm guessing that's what you have). Also, after you commented about the error and I edited the post, I realized that the React documentation I linked to says to bind the event handler, and isn't using ES6 class syntax, so they must have changed that and not updated the docs.

Comment: @augustinas What version of React are you using?

Comment: @augustinas Nevermind, I figured it out. If you do `.bind(this)` you get a warning. If you use `bind()` to pass additional args, like `.bind(this, x)`, you don't get a warning. https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/17453/

Comment: That's a very good spot! Didn't pay attention to the additional arguments. Thanks for a very educational afternoon :)